# How to exchange between each other value of variables in two(or more) classes in qt 5.6?

Tags: c++, qt, class

I work on for update STM mcu from qt program. I use qt for GUI but if I have a file that has specific format, I should begin update procedure. I send start char to STM and I must send update data according to the answer. I parsed my code to classes for usefull. So `UART` class send data to STM and read data incoming from STM mcu. `PROTOCOL` class should send update data to UART accordingly to incoming data.

My problem is here. I transfered data between classes but just one  direction(from `PROTOCOL` to `UART`). I sent data from `PROTOCOL` class to `UART` class. I need incoming data from STM mcu in `PROTOCOL` class. `UART` class read data but it can not send to `PROTOCOL` class(or `PROTOCOL` class can not read incoming data). How can I accomplish this?

**uart.h**

```
#ifndef UART_H
#define UART_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>


class UART : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UART(QObject *parent = 0);


    void Start();
    bool Updating = true;

    QByteArray received_new_data;

signals:

public slots:
    void ReadFromSerialPort();
    void WriteToSerialPort(const QByteArray &update_data, const qint64 &message_size);

private:
    const static QString DEBUG_IDENTIFIER;

    QSerialPort serial;
    QByteArray data;
    qint64 messageSize;


    void Initialize(const QString &portName);
    void Stop();

    static QString PORT_NAME;
};

#endif // UART_H
```

**uart.cpp**

```
  #include "uart.h"
    #include <QDebug>

    QString const UART::DEBUG_IDENTIFIER = "[UART]"; QString
    UART::PORT_NAME = "/dev/ttyS1";

    UART::UART( QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

    }

    void UART::Initialize(const QString &portName) {
        serial.setPortName(portName);
        serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
        serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);       
    }

    void UART::ReadFromSerialPort() {
        quint64 available_byte_amount = serial.bytesAvailable();

        if(available_byte_amount)
        {
            received_new_data = serial.readAll();
            qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "received_data: " << received_new_data;  
        } 
}



    void UART::WriteToSerialPort(const QByteArray &update_data, const
    qint64 &message_size) {

        data = update_data;                              //! max bytes lenght
        messageSize = message_size;

        //! When incoming hex "10" program continue send "U" char

            serial.write(data,messageSize);
            serial.flush();
            qDebug() <<"send";
            qDebug() << "data: " << received_new_data;
    }

    void UART::Start() {
        Initialize(PORT_NAME);

        if(serial.isOpen())
        {
            serial.clear();
            serial.clearError();
            connect(&serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(ReadFromSerialPort()));

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "(Start)"
                     << "Serial device is not open";
        }

        if(serial.error() == QSerialPort::NoError)
        {
            qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "No Error";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "An error occured:" << serial.errorString();
        } }

    void UART::Stop() {
        disconnect(&serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(ReadFromSerialPort())); }
```

**protocol.h**

```
#ifndef PROTOCOL_H
#define PROTOCOL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include "uart.h"

class UART;

class PROTOCOL : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PROTOCOL(UART *target_STM, QObject *parent = 0);

    static UART *ptr_uart;

    void gentnuma();
signals:

public slots:
    void readSTM(const QByteArray &readData);
    void writeSTM(const QByteArray &stm_data, const qint64 &stm_message_size);
    void read_data();

private:
    const static QString DEBUG_IDENTIFIER;

    QTimer *m_timer;

};

#endif // PROTOCOL_H
```

**protocol.cpp**

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

#include "protocol.h"
#include "uart.h"


QString const PROTOCOL::DEBUG_IDENTIFIER = "[PROTOCOL]";
UART *PROTOCOL::ptr_uart = NULL;


PROTOCOL::PROTOCOL(UART *target_uart, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    ptr_uart = target_uart;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(read_data()));
    timer->start(1);

}

void PROTOCOL::gentnuma()
{
    UART begin;
    QByteArray a = begin.received_new_data; 


    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "TEST:";
    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "COMING DATA:"<< a;  // I expected read data here
}


void PROTOCOL::readSTM(const QByteArray &readData)
{
    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "read_STM_request:" << readData;



}


void PROTOCOL::writeSTM(const QByteArray &stm_data, const qint64 &stm_message_size)
{

    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "send STM_data: " << stm_data;
    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "send STM_data size: " << stm_message_size;



        ptr_uart->WriteToSerialPort(stm_data,stm_message_size);     //send data to uart
}

void PROTOCOL::read_data()
{
    gentnuma();


}
```

Sorry bad English and long code lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is just a few steps away: have a `signal` in your `UART` class:

```
signals:
    void newData();
```

emit it when new data are read:

```
void UART::ReadFromSerialPort() 
{
    quint64 available_byte_amount = serial.bytesAvailable();

    if(available_byte_amount)
    {
        received_new_data = serial.readAll();
        qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "received_data: " << received_new_data;

        emit newData();  
    } 
}
```

You then connect the `UART` signal to the `PROTOCOL` slot you happen to already have, so, in `PROTOCOL` constructor, instead of

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(read_data()));
timer->start(1);
```

do:

```
connect(ptr_uart, SIGNAL(newData()), this, SLOT(read_data()));
```

This way, instead of polling for new data every second, your `PROTOCOL` class will be able to read new data from 'UART' whenever there's any.

But, watch out, you're doing it wrong here:

```
void PROTOCOL::gentnuma()
{
    UART begin;
    QByteArray a = begin.received_new_data; 


    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "TEST:";
    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "COMING DATA:"<< a;  // I expected read data here
}
```

since you're instantiating a new `UART` object out of the blue, and it has not (and never will have) new data to show. You already have a pointer to `UART` as a private class member, so you must use that one:

```
void PROTOCOL::gentnuma()
{
    QByteArray a = ptr_uart->received_new_data; 

    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "TEST:";
    qDebug() << DEBUG_IDENTIFIER << "COMING DATA:"<< a;  // I expected read data here
}
```

(just as a footnote: as far as I can see, that `ptr_uart` doesn't really need to be static ...)

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is worked. I can see important point after your answer(`QByteArray a = ptr_uart->received_new_data`). The examples I examined showed that these data could be read directly. So I didn't concentrate on `signals`.